Story Identification: pulp fiction series the end of the world, and Atlanteans stealing resources from other planets
I am trying to remember the name of a science fiction book series I borrowed from a library in BC, roughly 18-20 years ago.
Rough Plot Details

The first book involves a military operation in the jungle, most of the characters dies, but the main character gets the MacGuffin, a crystal skull.
In the subsequent books, most of the characters in each book die, with the male and female lead surviving.
By the end of the series, they learn that in a parallel world Atlanteans had destroyed their own planet by drilling to access the crystal at the core of the planet, but tapped an infinite energy source (which happened to be under Manhattan island.)
The main character dies closing the inter dimensional portals, in doing so crystalizes his own skull.

Other random details:

Psychic dolphins, who have been guiding the main characters, happen to live on the moon.
It turns out the crystal skulls are a map of dimensional travel, and as the characters move through the network they realize they are inside the skull.


This is Bob Mayer's Atlantis series. It starts:

Three areas on the Earth's surface defy explanation: The Bermuda Triangle, the Devil's Sea of Japan, and a small region of Cambodia. Inside these realms, planes have disappeared, ships have vanished, and, in Cambodia, an entire civilization has been lost.
Now, the destructive force behind these mysteries has been revealed. They invaded before. Ten thousand years ago. When they destroyed Atlantis.
And they're back.

The crystal skull first appears in the second book Bermuda Triangle when one of the characters Sin Fen has their head transformed to a crystal skull:

Then the bone itself changed, becoming clear, until it was pure crystal, totally suffused with the blue light. Suddenly a streak of blue shot out from the crystal skull toward the darkness of the approaching gate. Dane adjusted the camera, keeping it on Sin Fen - what had been Sin Fen - as more bolts of blue came out of the crystal skull, firing toward the gate.

It ends with Dane closing the gates and dying in the process:

Dane could feel the essence of the last Shadow still trying to shield the crystal. He focused his power and punched through, pouring his essence into the crystal. It was as if he dove into hot lava as he felt the immense power of the globe. He saw it then--that this crystal supplied the power that made all the portals work. He absorbed that power, drawing it in, feeling it build around him.
He remembered Sin Fen’s smile as she lay on top of the black pyramid, focusing its power against the Shadow. A similar smile crossed his face as he realized he was fulfilling his destiny. The crystal sphere exploded. Across multiple parallel worlds portals snapped out of existence.

The dolphins first appear in the third book Devil's Sea.

Thats definitely it! Dang that was fast.
You have no idea how long i spent trying to find it.
